# Combine output of ctc distribution with decoder output distribution?

Tags: transformer-model, linear-interpolation, ctc

[A visual representation of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzO9o.jpg)
I have a transformer encoder decoder structure, but want to jointly train with ctc. The encoder outputs(vis softmax) the ctc frame wise probabilities(batch x maxframes x vocab) , and the decoder outputs character probability distribution(batch x maxsequencelength x vocab). I want to combine them (joint decoding), how do I go about doing this?

What I tried:
I tried to linearly combine them using (1-lambda)Pctc + lambda*Pdecoder, but they are of different sizes, I need to decode or collapse the ctc to character probabilities, like remove all the blanks or repetitions but have no clue on how to go about that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To anyone reading this that's not a bot, I just want to perform many to one mapping in tensorflow, I could decode it and manually select the timestamps, but there has to be a simpler way right?